# Highcharts 'this' returning the same object twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I am simply trying to use the tooltip pointFormatter in Highcharts to return this.name (at least for now, I have some formatting to do after that). The problem I have is that this.point is returning the same object twice - it is the correct object, but it means that it is being displayed twice in my tooltip.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/MrClever88/LeL28nqr/13/) is a JSFiddle showing the issue, with the tooltip starting on line 242.

This is the code I have used:

```
tooltip: {
  pointFormatter: function(){
    var point = this.name;
    console.log(point);
    return point;
  },
  followPointer: true
}
```

Logging to the console confirms the fact that objects are being returned twice.

Any help would be much appreciated as I can't seem to find what could be causing the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: You are just editing the body of the tooltip to make it the exact same as the header. If you `return "abc"` instead you won't get that twice. You have to edit the title with `headerFormat` or maybe just use the `formatter` function instead of the `pointFormatter`.

Comment: Ah ok @Halvor, that makes sense. I did wonder if it was an issue with the header/body of the tooltip but I couldn't work it out. If you want to post that as an answer I'll accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pointFormatter` ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.pointFormatter)) only modifies the body of the tooltip, so currently your body is returning the exact same thing as the header. Two reasonable options:

- You can edit the title of the tooltip using `headerFormat` ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.headerFormat)) to differentiate them.
- You can alter the entire tooltip to your liking using the `formatter` ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.formatter)) function.

Note that the `formatter` does not exist under `plotOptions`, where you code currently resides. It is only available through the root `tooltip`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the pointer over multiple elements.
So your code works good, but there are a lot of overlay, that's why it repeat multiple point name.
Declare a var tmpPoint in:

```
$(function () {
var tmpPoint;
```

and than:

```
tooltip: {
            pointFormatter: function(){
            var point = this.name;
            if (tmpPoint!=point){
              tmpPoint=point;
              console.log('bb'+point);
              return point;
            }
          },
          followPointer: true
        },
```